# HtmlAgilityPack - parsing website with cookies/tabs using c#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

When I want to get data from webpage i usually use HtmlAgilityPack with an HtmlDocument object which uses the main web url of the site and then use HtmlNode object with the main table for example with all the data that i want from the page and copy it's XPath into the input. Example:

```
HtmlDocument hDocument = GetHtmlDocumentFromUrl("http://someweb.com");
HtmlNode mainNode = hDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='XpathOfTableWithData']");
```

After doing that, i can loop into the childNodes of this main node and get what i want, but there are websites which contain "tabs" and they are like newer style than older type of websites and then i just get the main node to be null.
How can i get this information with c# and HtmlAgilityPack if the page is with cookies and have tabs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 'tabs' should still be html elements that are enhanced using CSS. If you review one of the sites in question, you should see the structure and amend your code accordingly.

Comment: But how? The Html Node which is assigned to the xPath is always null and i tried many different ones.